# P-value in scipy.stats does not reflect the reality

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

I am not sure whether this is a question for Stack Overflow or for Math Stack Exchange.

I have data about the cost of crashes of cars A, and the data about the cost of crashes of cars B.

There were 15 992 crashes of type B, with the total cost of 19 890 980. Average cost of a crash of cars B was 1541.808.

Then, there were 2760 crashes of type A with the total cost of 4 255 390. The average cost of a crash of cars A was 1243.808.

It is apparent that the mean of the cost of crashes of cars A should be lower than the one of cars B. I want to test this using a t-test. The null hypothesis is "The means are equal". The alpha is 5%.

However, when I run the following in python

```
ttest_ind(table[B], table2[A],  alternative="less",equal_var=False)
```

The result I get is this: (and the p value would indicate that mean of the cost of the crash of cars B is NOT less than the mean of A, which does not make sense).

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=3.417269886834147, pvalue=0.9996071028578007)
```

If I, however, run this (without the alternative)

```
ttest_ind(table[B], table2[A], equal_var=False)
```

I get

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=3.417269886834147, pvalue=0.0007857942843984687)
```

Why does the first function which uses "alternative" produce the weirdly high p-value? Is there something I understand incorrectly about the p-values?

Comment: This may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513930/correctly-using-hypothesis-testing-to-conclude-x-mean-is-less-than-y-mean

Comment: When you do not specify the **alternative**, you are using the default which would be the same as  `ttest_ind(table[B], table2[A], equal_var=False, alternative='two-sided')` .

Comment: From what I understand, it is the difference between the null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a link to the data ?

Answer (score 1):

You have your sample order inverted. Use instead:

```py
ttest_ind(table[A], table2[B],  alternative="less", equal_var=False)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html), under the `alternative` argument:

> ‘less’: the mean of the distribution underlying the first sample is less than the mean of the distribution underlying the second sample.